# An item with the same key has already been added when loading Kendo MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate a Kendo mvcGrid and I keep getting the error An item with the same key has already been added.

I have seen elsewhere that duplicate model properties is the likeliest source of the problem but I have no duplicate properties in my model. I've even simplified everything to just a basic mock up to eliminate as many possible variables as possible..and I cant get the grid to load data.

I've tried it as a Html.Partial where its not loaded initially because of a empty model and then loading it through jquery...Ive tried with passing in am empty model so that the grid will load initially without data and then doing a datasource refresh...no luck there either.  Basically as soon as I try to add content to the grid with a populated model I get the error and no data is loaded.

Been fighting this issue for 2 days now and had no luck.  Ill post my code here maybe someone else can see what I'm missing.

One variable that cant change is the grid resides on a partial view with a model different from its parent view.

in the parent view I have tried both

```
<div id ="columnkgrid">@{Html.RenderPartial("Columns", new TestFieldIssue.Models.FieldListModel());}</div>
```

and

```
<div id="columnkgrid">@Html.Partial("Columns", new TestFieldIssue.Models.FieldListModel())</div>
```

either way will succeed in posting a grid with no data..it has no data yet because its populated by the selection of a value in a dropdown list.

so as to not over complicate the sample I've just set a hard coded value in the jquery function I have been using to refresh the grid.

```
function loadgrid() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var val = 1;
    grid.dataSource.read({ table_pk: val });
    grid.refresh();    
}
```

the grid code in the partial once again kept it simple without any bells and whistles just to test.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.fields)
                        .DataSource(data => data
                            .Ajax()
                            .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.field_pk))
                            .Read(r => r.Action("Columns","Home"))
                            )

                        .Name("grid")
                        .Columns(c =>
                            {                              
                                c.Bound(m => m.field_name).Title("Field Name").Width(100);
                            })
    )
```

and the controller methods loading some mock data

```
public ActionResult Columns(int? table_pk)
        {
            FieldListModel model;
            if (table_pk == null)
            {
                model = GetEmptyColumns();
            }
            else
            {
                model = GetColumns();
            }
            return PartialView("Columns", model);
        }
        public FieldListModel GetColumns()
        {
            FieldListModel model = new FieldListModel();
            model.fields = new List<FieldModel>();
            model.fields.Add(new FieldModel { field_name = "field1", field_pk = 1 });
            model.fields.Add(new FieldModel { field_name = "field2", field_pk = 2 });
            model.fields.Add(new FieldModel { field_name = "field3", field_pk = 3 });
            return model;
        }
        public FieldListModel GetEmptyColumns()
        {
            FieldListModel model = new FieldListModel();
            model.fields = new List<FieldModel>();
            model.fields.Add(new FieldModel { field_name = "", field_pk = 0 });
            return model;
        }
```

and a very simple Model

```
public class FieldListModel
    {
        public List<FieldModel> fields { get; set; }
    }
 public class FieldModel
    {
        public int field_pk { get; set; }
        public string field_name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Any error in browser console window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made few changes to run your code (correct version of Kendo and JQuery). May be those related to setup at my machine. I was able to reproduce the problem.

Then I changed the action code and was able to see the values populated in Grid:

```
public ActionResult Columns(int? table_pk, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    FieldListModel model;

    if (table_pk == null)
    {
        model = GetEmptyColumns();
    }
    else
    {
        model = GetColumns();
    }
    return Json(model.fields.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

The change is accepting an additional parameter in action method of type `DataSourceRequest`. The Kendo grid wraps request in this object to specify sorting and paging information. The grid itself gets updated with data wrapped under `DataSourceRequest`  object (note in return statement). More information [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding).

Comment: Thanks so much!  Was banging my head on that for days.  For anyone else needing this solution..don't forget to add the using using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions; to the controller.